# How can I make my main if, elseIf and else to do the same thing as my main if does without getting "duplicate" errors?

Tags: java

My main If statement asks for an input. If it's "february",It goes to the next steps. I want these same steps for my main elseif and else after they do their own part. 
I also want to convert "february" to "allUppercase" or "alllowerCase" to make it insensitive. But I get an error when I'm writing ""if(s1.toLowerCase("february"))"" 
Thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Compare {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] months1 = {"january","march","april","may","june","july","augest","september","october","november","december"};
    String s1 = getInput("Enter a month ");
    if(s1.equals("february")) {
        System.out.println("It's time to go to the Disneyland !");
        String s2 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
        if(s2.equals("february")) {
            System.out.println("You already won a Disneyland ticket! Try another month.");
            String s3 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
            String[] months = {"january","march","april","may","june","july","augest","september","october","november","december"};               
            if(Arrays.asList(months).contains(s3.toLowerCase())) {
                  System.out.println("You will go to Paris");
            }else{
                 String s4 = getInput("Leave your name and phone number. We will call you back. ");
                 System.out.println("Thanks for visiting! Goodbye !" + s4);
            }    
        }
    }else if(Arrays.asList(months1).contains(s1.toLowerCase())){
        System.out.print("Sorry we don't have any specials yet");

    }else{
        System.out.print("Phahaha:))) choose sthg else");
    }

}
            private static String getInput(String prompt) {
                BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.print(prompt);
                System.out.flush();

    try {
        return stdin.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
      }

 }
```

}

Comment: Well yes, `String.toLowerCase` doesn't take a string argument. Did you mean `s1.toLowerCase().equals("february")`? Note that this isn't the best way of performing a case-insensitive comparison anyway - consider using a `java.text.Collator` instead or `String.equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: Yes exactly...I want that..Thanks for helping!

Comment: I was looking for "s1.toLowerCase().equals("february")" yes this is what I want

Comment: Well, as I said, it would be better to use `equalsIgnoreCase`...

Comment: like (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("february")) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed `if(s1.toLowerCase("february"))` is a compile error since `s1.toLowerCase("february")` returns a string and `if ()` expects a boolean.

use `if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("february"))` ` to compare your string ignoring case

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
s1.equalsIgnoreCase("february")
```

to compare your string ignoring case:

> equalsIgnoreCase compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.

Anyway, if Jon suggests using `java.text.Collator` I'd trust him!

Answer (score 1):

As for you other question, you can make a method on the compare class, outside the main method to encapsulate all the code you want each if statement to execute, and call that method from each if statement.

Comment: aha...I'm alittle bit confused:D